# Angular2 component design?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I've been working with Angular2 for several month now and have never understood this one problem.

Assuming we have a parent component, a host component and a child component;
Parent component loads a list of data. On item selected brings host component through router outlet, and the child component is loaded through router outlet in host's template.

Let's say that parent does a request to get all and the host component has the routing rules which include the ID, and it does request to the service to get by ID.

Now, I want to simply pass down that object to the child component, how can I do it?

Why isnt an option like  available or how can I achieve similar behavior? If the "id" is part of the host component's routing - than the child cant access that ID from the routeparams.

I don't want to use a shared service and simply put stuff there as that solution is very trivial and I just find it being a hack. I want my components to be more independent and have a precise workflow. I really love passing data through @Input(), but it's unavailable. I don't want to do two requests to get by ID either.

I hate using observable data services for this either because it's so hard to keep when is loaded when in your head, that at some point there is always some crash because the template loaded before some observable got resolved in some component 2 levels up.

Perhaps I am missing something essential and there is a good solution available, or perhaps I have to change the architecture and not load the child components through router outlet? Is there a design flaw?

Comment: Is this about passing data to components added by the router? There is currently no other way than a shared service. You don't need to use an observable if the value is available before the routed component gets added. If you use `|async` and `x?.y` then there should be no problem with data arriving later.

Comment: Why would a service be a "hack"? That actually could improve the responsiveness of the page and would likely centralize the logic of data access nicely. It's a subtle difference between a component receiving a full data object as `@Input()` and just receiving an `ID` which then must retrieve the data from a service.

Comment: Doesnt it make all the components dependent on these services, where as I would like my component, given the input of type X do some work and display the view (output Y)?